# Working with multiple DatePickers in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I know this sounds some nonsense but I tried whatever I can and these seems quite long and also not genuine and so looking here so, plz anyone could up things in frame here. Anythings modifications with code will be appreciated.

I do have four datepickers. They are as StartDate, EndDate, RelationStartDate and RelationEndDate with a dropdown(ParentDepartment). Now here my requirement is while the page is loaded I have to hide RelationStartDate and RelationEndDate and when a value within the dropdown is selected then I have to show the corresponding Datepickers.
Now here a user can select a date or enter manually with keyboard. He haves all the option can use tab, etc;(if any).
Now the main thing here is StartDate upon selected the EndDate should be greater than Start Date and when when StartDate, EndDate and value from a dropdown is selected then RelationStartDate and RelationEndDate should be enabled and then the RelationStartDate should lies between StartDate and EndDate. In similar fashion the RelationEndDate should be between RelationStartDate and EndDate.
After performing all the above the user if he is going back to StartDate then modifying StartDate and if this date is less than EndDate then should display an error within a div, similarly upon EndDate selection it shouldn't be less than StartDate and this rule apply for RelationStartDate and RelationEndDate.
Note: A user can modifying a datepicker any time and alerts should not be used to specify user mistakes instead a div will be preferred.
Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {       
        $("input[id$='Date']").on('click keyup keypress keydown change', function () {
            var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
            var endDate = $("#EndDate").val();
            var relstartDate = $("#RelationStartDate").val();
            var relendDate = $("#RelationEndDate").val();
            function checkIn() {
                if ((startDate) == '') {
                    var status
                    $("input[id$='Date']").val('');
                    $('#divErrorMsg').text('Please Select Start Date');
                    $('#StartDate').focus();
                    status = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            /*Start Date*/
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'StartDate') {
                if (new Date(startDate) > new Date(endDate)) {
                    $("input[id$='Date']").not('#StartDate').val('');
                    $('#divErrorMsg').text('Start Date Should be Less than End Date');
                    $(this).focus();
                }
                else {
                    $('#divErrorMsg').text('');
                }
            }
            /*End Date*/
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'EndDate') {
                var status = checkIn();
                if (status != true) {
                    if (new Date(endDate) < new Date(startDate)) {
                        $("input[id$='Date']").not('#StartDate, #EndDate').val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('End Date Should be Greater than Start Date');
                        $(this).focus();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('');
                    }
                }
            }
            /*Relations Start Date*/
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'RelationStartDate') {
                if (($('#StartDate').val() !='' && $('#EndDate').val()!='')) {
                    if (new Date(relstartDate) <= new Date(startDate) && new Date(relstartDate) >= new Date(endDate)) {
                        //$('#RelationEndDate').val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Relation Start Date Should be between Start Date');
                        $(this).focus();
                    }
                    else if ((new Date(relstartDate) < new Date(startDate))) {
                        $('#RelationEndDate').val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Relation Start Date Should be between Start Date');
                        $(this).focus();
                    }
                    else if ((new Date(relstartDate) > new Date(endDate))) {
                        $('#RelationEndDate').val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Relation Start Date Should be between Start Date');
                        $(this).focus();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($('#StartDate').val() == '') {
                        $("input[id$='Date']").val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Please Select Start Date');
                        $('#StartDate').focus();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Please Select End Date');
                        $("input[id$='Date']").not('#StartDate').val('');
                        $('#EndDate').focus();
                    }
                }
            }                
            /*Relation  End Date Starts here*/
            if ($(this).attr('id') == 'RelationEndDate') {
                debugger;

                if (($('#StartDate').val() != '' && $('#EndDate').val() != '') && $('#RelationStartDate').val() != '') {
                    if (($('#StartDate').val() != '' && $('#EndDate').val() != '')) {
                        if (new Date(relendDate) < new Date(relstartDate) && new Date(relendDate) > new Date(endDate)) {
                            $('#divErrorMsg').text('Relation End Date Should be between Relation Start Date & End Date');
                            $(this).focus();
                        }
                        else if ((new Date(relendDate) < new Date(relstartDate))) {
                            $('#divErrorMsg').text('Relation End Date Should be between Relation Start Date & End Date');
                            $(this).focus();
                        }
                        else if ((new Date(relendDate) > new Date(endDate))) {
                            $('#divErrorMsg').text('Relation End Date Should be between Relation Start Date & End Date');
                            $(this).focus();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#divErrorMsg').text('');
                            $('#RelationStartDate').focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($('#StartDate').val() == '') {
                        $("input[id$='Date']").val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Please Select Start Date');
                        $('#StartDate').focus();
                    }
                    else if ($('#EndDate').val() == '') {
                        $("input[id$='Date']").not('#StartDate').val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Please Select End Date');
                        $('#EndDate').focus();
                    }
                    else if ($('#RelationStartDate').val() == '') {
                        $("input[id$='Date']").not('#StartDate, #EndDate').val('');
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('Please Select Relation Start Date');
                        $('#RelationStartDate').focus();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorMsg').text('');
                        $('#RelationEndDate').focus();
                    }
                }                   
            }
        });       
        $("input[id$='Date']").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", $('#StartDate').val());
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate");
                $("#RelationStartDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", $('#StartDate').val());
                $("#RelationEndDate").datepicker("option", 'minDate', $('#RelationStartDate').val());
                $("#RelationStartDate").datepicker("option", 'maxDate', $('#EndDate').val());
                $("#RelationEndDate").datepicker("option", 'maxDate', $('#EndDate').val());
            },
        }).css('vertical-align', 'top');
           });
```

```
//Here is the Html    
<div class="editor-label">StartDate</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">EndDate</div>  
<div class="editor-field">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)                    
 </div>
<div class="editor-label">ParentDepartment</div>
<div class="editor-field">
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentDepartmentId, new 
 SelectList(@ViewBag.ParentDepartmentId, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName"),   
 "--Select--")                    
</div>
<div class="editor-label">RelationStartDate</div>      
 <div class="editor-field">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationStartDate)  </div>                  
 <div class="editor-label">RelationEndDate </div>              
 <div class="editor-field">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RelationEndDate)
</div>
```

The above code has some defects and is too lengthy. Anything which make the goal achieved + Short in length will be a favour. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please tell us what errors you are getting so we can help

Comment: @OurManInBananas Thanks for reading. The main thing here is I want to reduce the amount of code so that it looks neat and clean. Also after selecting all the dates when I modify StartDate and if it is greater than end date then I am not gettin error any clues. Thanks again

Comment: @OurManInBananas any suggestions plz.